# Can Dexron IID ATF be used in place of Dexron II ATF?

Tags: power-steering, mitsubishi, atf, pajero

My vehicle manual states I must use Dexron II ATF fluid for my power steering.
When I shop around, I often find Dexron IID ATF locally. Can I use this, or must I find something without the **D** after the II?

NOTE: Vehicle is a 2001 Mitsubishi Pajero/Montero 3.5 GDI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dexron-II(D) is what you should actually be looking for as technically, you won't find "Dexron-II" because it never *truly* existed. Dexron-II(C) came out in 1973 and was followed in 1975 by Dexron-II(D). The letter designation is actually the iteration of the Dexron product release. Since your vehicle was made in 2001, they were looking for Dexron-II(D) even though they only stated "Dexron-II".